# Logical "and" for multiple logical vectors

Tags: r, logical-operators

If I have a number of logical statements (logical vectors in general), like `x>1`, `y!=1` and `sin(x)<0`, is there a function `AND` in R:

```
AND(x>1, y!=1, sin(x)<0)
```

giving the same results as

```
x>1 & y!=1 & sin(x)<0
```

Note, the number of vectors are variable, and not restricted to 3.

Comment: If `x` and `y` are singles (not vectors), why not `all(x>1, y!=1, sin(x)<0)`?

Comment: I think your scalar case is certainly powerful and flexible, but too many times I see questions with insufficient understanding of `&` versus `&&`, in both directions. `all` is not truly vector-functional here, of course, so adding the distinction to your answer might be useful to follow-on questioners.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned by [@r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans), if we only work with scalar rather than vector, we can use `all` safely:

```
all(1 < 4, 5 > 7, 6 == 6)
```

My answer below addresses the case when you work with several logical vectors, and would like to take parallel / element-wise `all`. As a reproducible example, suppose we have logical vectors:

```
set.seed(0)

a1 <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 5, replace = TRUE)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

a2 <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 5, replace = TRUE)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

a3 <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 5, replace = TRUE)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

We aim for a solution that are not subject to the number of logical vectors.

---

**Option 1**

We can use `Reduce` and `"&"`:

```
## define a function
AND1 <- function (...)  Reduce("&", list(...))

AND1(a1, a2, a3)
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

The **binary** operator `"&"` only works with two inputs, so we can do

```
"&"(a1, a2)
```

but not

```
"&"(a1, a2, a3)
```

`Reduce` is here to help, by iteratively applying `"&"`:

```
tmp <- "&"(a1, a2)
"&"(a2, a3)
```

---

The following two options first collect all logical vectors into a matrix. Then option 2a uses row-wise `all`, while option 2b uses `rowSums`.

**Option 2a**

```
AND2a <- function (...) {
  X <- do.call(cbind, list(...))
  base::apply(X, 1L, all)
  }

AND2a (a1, a2, a3)
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

**Option 2b**

```
AND2b <- function (...) {
  X <- do.call(cbind, list(...))
  ## `TRUE` is 1 and `FALSE` is 0 when doing arithmetic sum
  ## all `TRUE` is as same as row sums equal to `ncol(X)` or `dim(X)[2]`
  base::rowSums(X) == dim(X)[2L]
  }

AND2b (a1, a2, a3)
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```